# Why is .NET Framework a valid build target when using VS for Mac

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

Using Visual Studio for Mac 7.3.3, why am I able to create solutions that target .NET Framework 4.x?

Reproduction steps:

1. (file->new solution->other->.NET->Console Project) or 
   (file->new solution->other->.NET->asp.net MVC Project)
2. Right click the project and check under Build->General, you can see that you are targeting .NET Framework 4.x.
   [image: Targeting .NET Framework on VS for Mac]

How is this possible/why is this valid? My understand was that .NET Framework was only supported by Windows, and the Linux and OSX were limited to creating .NET Core apps.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework apps can be run on Mac/Linux with Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Aha, so is it just using Mono behind the scenes?

Comment: If it helps, Visual Studio for Mac is really Monodevelop, rebranded.